# BigQuery and GA: Some ecom metrics like product revenue not assigned correctly to product list name

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Just as is shown in the Google Analytics User Interface, I'd like to get the product revenue per product list via the query as is seen below. However, all product revenue is assigned to '(not set)', while in the UI it's assigned to the product lists.

Also, it looks like in BQ only product list impressions and product list clicks (BQ field hits.eCommerceAction.action_type) are assigned to product lists. Product detail views, checkouts, and unique purchases also do not seem to be assigned to product lists, while in the GA UI they do. The same issue as with the product revenue I guess.

Does anyone know how to get the desired result?

```
SELECT
  prod.productListName AS ProdListName,
  SUM(prod.productRevenue)/1000000 AS PrRev
FROM
  `[project id].[dataset id].ga_sessions_*` AS t, t.hits AS hits, hits.product AS prod
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20181103'
  AND '20181103'
GROUP BY
  ProdListName
ORDER BY PrRev DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hits.product.productListName field is set for product list view and product list click actions only. 
You can get revenue per product list this way:

```
#standardSQL
select
l.productListName as listName,
ROUND(SUM(p.productRevenue), 2) as productRevenue
from
(select
  concat (fullVisitorId, ".", cast(visitId as string), ".", cast(visitStartTIme as string), ".", cast(totals.visits as string)) as sessionId,
  h.hitNumber as hitNumber,
  p.v2ProductName as productName,
  p.productRevenue/1000000 as productRevenue
from
  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`, unnest(hits) h, unnest(h.product) as p
  where h.eCommerceAction.action_type ='6')p
 join 
/* (select
  concat (fullVisitorId, ".", cast(visitId as string), ".", cast(visitStartTIme as string), ".", cast(totals.visits as string)) as sessionId,
  p.v2ProductName as productName,
  p.productListName as productListName,
  MAX(h.hitNumber) as hitNumber_
from
  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`, unnest(hits) h, unnest(h.product) as p
  where h.eCommerceAction.action_type = '1'
  group by 1,2,3
  order by 1 )l */
(select
    sessionId,
    productName,
    productListName,
    hitNumber_
    from(
        select
        sessionId,
        productName,
        productListName,
        hitNumber_,
        row_number() over (partition by sessionId, productName order by hitNumber_ desc) as rn
        from
            (select
              concat (fullVisitorId, ".", cast(visitId as string), ".", cast(visitStartTIme as string), ".", cast(totals.visits as string)) as sessionId,
              p.v2ProductName as productName,
              p.productListName as productListName,
              h.hitNumber as hitNumber_
            from
              `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`, unnest(hits) h, unnest(h.product) as p
              where h.eCommerceAction.action_type = '1'))
              where rn = 1
)l
  on
  p.sessionId = l.sessionId
  and p.productName = l.productName
  where p.hitNumber > l.hitNumber_
  group by listName
  ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Pavlo, now the product revenue is attributed to the lists. But it has to be said, there is still a (rather small) difference between the GA interface and BQ results, and the following factor contributes to this difference: if within the same session the same product is clicked across different lists, in the GA UI the product revenue is attributed to only 1 of these lists (that is the one that is interacted with the last), while in the query above the total product revenue for that product within that session is attributed to all these lists. Do you know how to workaround this?

Comment: Timo, I updated 2nd subquery to provide more accurate data. Old part of query is in /* */. Still, there could be a small % of discrepancies with GA UI, because if during same session product click happened after same product purchase, this click aren't part of final aggregation, because click hit number is greater than purchase hit number.  You can try to remove 'where p.hitNumber > l.hitNumber_' statement and check do output closer to GA UI in this case.

Comment: Thanks again Pavlo. The difference with the GA UI remains, but I guess the last query is a bit more accurate. I'll use this one! Too bad Google doesn't provide an easier and 100%-matching with the UI solution for this in BQ. I also miss an exact definition from Google how product revenue is assigned to the product list in the UI, in order to also fix the difference we now still see between the UI and BQ.